# Loading predefined symbology in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, legend, import

I have a couple data sets with these files (image 1). When I load the symbology, I get random colors (image 2). The public domain I downloaded the files from have a predefined symbology (image 3), is there anyway I can load it?

[image: file list]

[image: random color map and symbology colours]

[image: predefined symbology colours]

Comment: Welcome! Are you able to share the link to the public domain dataset?  Generally, QGIS allows layer style files (.qml) and styled layer descriptor (.sld) files to be loaded which allows us to make use of pre-defined styles and makes symbolising layers easier.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! The dataset is from here, under data sources, geoscience, 250 ,000 scale geology  --> https://gisappl.saskatchewan.ca/Html5Ext/index.html?viewer=GeoAtlas

Comment: PGerrits, I see my issue here potentially. They use the Esri Arc GIS platform, am I able do to any kind of conversion?

Comment: Best way is to go back to the data provider and request a test file that relates rock type to color- preferably as a .sld file. They should be able to give you this even if they have to write it out from Arcgis. If not a .sld file then at least a text file with the color notation as RGB.

Comment: Leigh, thanks for your response! I do have this sort of text file. How would I incorperate the text file in for the color symbology? --> https://maps2.gov.mb.ca/arcgis/rest/services/MG_GEOLOGY_CLIENT/MapServer/136

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. In QGIS, add an ArcGIS REST Server Connection using the following URL:

   https://gis.saskatchewan.ca/arcgis/rest/services/Economy/P_1_250000_Scale_Geology/MapServer

[image]

2. Add the vector layer `250K Bedrock Geology`
3. Right click on the layer in the layers widget -> Export -> Save as QGIS Layer Style File... -> save the symbology as QML file.

You could try to apply this QML file to your downloaded data (right click on the layer in the layers widget -> Symbology -> Style -> Load style...)

[image]

Comment: Thank you Path!!

Comment: My pleasure @Ebillz If the answer solves your question, you may "accept" it (meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: Hey @pathmapper, how do I find the URL you provided in 1)? I would like to use this technique for a few other areas.

Comment: You could use the browser developer tools / network monitor - Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor , Chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/https://gisappl.saskatchewan.ca/Html5Ext/index.html?viewer=GeoAtlasdocs/devtools/network/ . Just zoom and pan https://gisappl.saskatchewan.ca/Html5Ext/index.html?viewer=GeoAtlas to an area of interest, select only the layer you are interested in, clear all network logs, pan the map a little bit and inspect the requested URL.