# How to use ArcGIS MapServer as basemap in QGIS to create webmap using QGIS2WEB plugin

Tags: qgis, web-mapping, qgis2web

I'm pretty new to using open source GIS software such as QGIS (my main experience is using Esri's ArcGIS products). However my current client does not have an Esri licence and so is requiring the creation of a webmap using opensource. So far I have managed to create multiple webmap files using the QGIS2WEB plugin with opensource as a basemap but I instead would like to use a basemap from an ArcGIS Server - I have connected the server to QGIS but when I try and use QGIS2WEB to export the webmap it removes the basemap or just simply crashes.

Any advice?

Comment: The following error message is displayed : 
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ' FileName'

Comment: Maybe the answer to this question will help you  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/407512/loading-predefined-symbology-in-qgis

Comment: @pathmapper Hi. Can you answer this question?